# sshtunnel keyboard-interactive

Tags: python, unix, paramiko, ssh-tunnel

I'd like to use sshtunnel without authentication for a password or private key for the 2nd Example (Fig.2)  given in the [docs](https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

from the docs (slightly modified for the private-server part):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------

                            |
-------------+              |    +----------+               +---------
    LOCAL    |              |    |  REMOTE  |               | PRIVATE
    CLIENT   | <== SSH ========> |  SERVER  | <== SSH ==>   | SERVER
-------------+              |    +----------+               +---------
                            |
                         FIREWALL

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The allowed authentication method is "keyboard-interactive" (multi-step authentication) as described in [Erick's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903875/python-paramiko-client-multifactor-authentication)

So what I do already have from above is a paramiko transport- and a paramiko channel object. My question:
how to plug these both objects into the sshtunnel Forwarder class to achieve something like this in unix shell (local port forwarding):
`ssh -L localhost:port-local-client:PRIVATE_SERVER:port-private-server user@REMOTE_SERVER`

Here's some example-code from Erick's post:
What I want to achieve is to use the transport for further cmds, see below ...

```
import forward # the forward.py script, referenced by Kirk

#Create a socket and connect it to PORT on the REMOTE_SERVER
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("REMOTE_SERVER", PORT))

#Make a Paramiko Transport object using the socket
transport = paramiko.Transport(sock)

#Tell Paramiko that the Transport is going to be used as a client
transport.start_client(timeout=10)

#Begin authentication with "my_handler" being a callable which returns the server prompt-list
transport.auth_interactive(USERNAME, my_handler)

# this doesn't come back, since class "ForwardServer" ... serve_forever() ...
forward.forward_tunnel(PORT, "PRIVATE_SERVER", PORT, transport)

# However, what I'd like to accomplish is to "surf" the transport /channel and
# operate cmds on it as such:

#Opening a session creates a channel along the socket to the server
channel = transport.open_session(timeout=10)

#Now the channel can be used to execute commands
stdout = channel.exec_command("touch Hello_Private_Server!")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12106387/2430857 seems like what you're after

Comment: Thanks!
The [Transport class](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/transport.html) looks promising: request_port_forward(address, port, handler=None)

Comment: So in the end I didn't need the sshtunnel, just paramiko. For the way to use paramiko to accomplish the `ssh -L` option, please see below ...
Thank you so much Martin, pointing to the right links!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I was after these 2 lines ...

```
# span the local port forwarding (ssh -L)
REMOTE_SERVER_Channel = transport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", (PRIVATE_SERVER, PORT), (LOCAL_CLIENT, PORT))

# create a new paramiko-client (with corresponding policy)
...
# and crack it open with the distant channel
tunnelClient.connect(PRIVATE_SERVER, username=ssh-USERNAME, password=ssh-PASSWORD, sock=REMOTE_SERVER_Channel)
```

So, what do you think, is this attempt too 'wordy' or am I using the paramiko classes (Channel, Client, Transport) efficiently?